# Cannot install build-essential/gcc/g++ after upgrade to 17.04

Tags: upgrade, dependencies, 17.04

Since upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04, I can no longer install `gcc-7` or `g++-7` from the http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu repository. In fact I cannot even install `build-essential`.

Under *Software & Updates* > *Other Software*, the repository is listed like this:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu zesty main
```

Trying to install `build-essential`:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:5.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

However:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.1-8ubuntu1) 5.4.1 20170304
...
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.1-8ubuntu1) 5.4.1 20170304
...
```

So how can I install `build-essential` again?

Comment: Considering the gcc package in zesty is 4:6.3.0-2ubuntu1 maybe your upgrade didn't go so well. At the least you should have purged that toolchain ppa before you started the upgrade process. Maybe try downloading the actual packages & installing manually. (or save yourself some time & do a fresh install

Comment: @doug I have done so many fresh installs because every time you touch this system it breaks. How would I know what to purge before doing an upgrade? I expect that the upgrade process doesn't magically break something. :(

Comment: I was getting this error and just ran `sudo apt upgrade` and it fixed it. You may not want to upgrade though.

Answer (score 7):

So I was able to install `build-essential` again by following these steps:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:5.2) but it is not going to be installed
```

A `gcc` version greater 5.2 is required, so lets try to install `gcc`.

```
$ sudo apt install gcc
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gcc : Depends: cpp (>= 4:6.3.0-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: gcc-6 (>= 6.3.0-9~) but it is not going to be installed
```

Okay. Something else is missing. Let’s try installing that.

```
$ sudo apt install cpp
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp : Depends: cpp-6 (>= 6.3.0-9~) but it is not going to be installed
```

Still nothing. Trying again.

```
$ sudo apt install cpp-6
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-6 : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) but 6.3.0-18ubuntu2~16.04 is to be installed
```

Once again.

```
$ sudo apt install gcc-6-base
...
gcc-6-base is already the newest version (6.3.0-18ubuntu2~16.04).
```

So here I don’t know what exactly went wrong. It should be noted that there is a `16.04` string at the end of that version number. That seemed odd. I removed that package.

```
$ sudo apt remove gcc-6-base
```

Now I was able to install `build-essential` again. This will also reinstall `gcc-6-base`.

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential
```

**Remaining problem:**

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
...
The following packages have been kept back:
  cpp g++ gcc
```

Root of the problem is similar as above, `gcc-7-base` is faulty but I can’t simply remove it, since I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.1.0-5ubuntu2~16.04) but it is not going to be installed
 va-driver-all : Depends: mesa-va-drivers but it is not going to be installed or
                          vdpau-va-driver but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

**Danger Zone**:

I managed to resolve this issue with the following steps:

```
$ sudo apt install aptitude
$ sudo dpkg --force-all -P gcc-7-base
$ sudo dpkg --force-all -P gcc-7-base:i386
$ sudo aptitude install gcc-7-base
```

This is super dangerous and might break your installation. Executing `dpkg --force-all -P` will remove a package forcefully, ignoring any dependencies on this package. Following this by a regular `apt upgrade` might remove almost all relevant software from your installation.

I was only able to recover from there by usind `aptitude` which resolved every dependency issue I had.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue while upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. I have written the detailed solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1274779/840045). But for the sake of convenience I will reproduce the key points here.

Remove all dependent libraries (`autoremove`) and install all missing libraries using `sudo apt-get -f install` (`-f` means `--fix-missing`)

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Install `ubuntu toolchain` from PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

Install `aptitude`.

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Recursively try installing the broken libraries until you solve the conflict by upgrading or fixing a specific library. In my case I had to fix `libstdc++6`

```
$ sudo aptitude -f install build-essential
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential cpp{a} cpp-5{a} g++{a} g++-5{a} gcc{a} gcc-5{a} libasan2{a} libcc1-0{ab} 
  libcilkrts5{a} libgcc-5-dev{a} liblsan0{ab} libmpx0{a} libstdc++-5-dev{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gcc-5-base libstdc++6{b} 
2 packages upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 29.6 MB of archives. After unpacking 100 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04) but 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 is installed.
 libcc1-0 : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04) but 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 is installed.
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04) but 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 is installed.
```

As `build-essential` needs `gcc-5`.

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install gcc-5

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-5 : Depends: cpp-5 (= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 is to be installed
         Depends: libcc1-0 (>= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libgcc-5-dev (= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But `gcc-5` in turn depends on `cpp-5`

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install cpp-5

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 is to be installed
```

`cpp-5` depends on `gcc-5-base`. Here you can see there is a specific conflict. Aptitide gives multiple choices to solve the conflict. In my case upgrading the `libstdc++6` solvd the problem.

```
$ sudo aptitude -f install gcc-5-base
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  gcc-5-base{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 67.6 kB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) but it is not going to be installed.
open: 115; closed: 488; defer: 35; conflict: 58                                                          .The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:                        
1)     gcc-5-base [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 (now, xenial-security, xenial-updates)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Upgrade the following packages:                                                                     
1)      libstdc++6 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 (now, xenial-security, xenial-updates) -> 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.0
```

Finally, now the conflict is resolved try installing `build-essential` again.

```
$ sudo aptitude -f install build-essential
```

Good Luck!

Comment: This worked for me - thanks! For anyone else getting the following error (`/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libiconv.so.2 is not a symbolic link`) when installing `build-essential` via aptitude, renaming `libiconv.so.2` to `libiconv.backup.so.2` solved the issue for me. This is caused by there being a `libiconv.backup.so.2` and `libiconv.backup.so.2.6.0` file in the directory which confuses things. More details (https://stackoverflow.com/q/11542255/10002593)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem but the solution is actually pretty simple
so it saying: The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:5.2) but it is not going to be installed
```

the just install the the package on the 'depends'
do :

```
apt-get install gcc
```

and then it will says :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc : Depends: cpp (= 4:9.2.1-3.1) but 4:8.3.0-1 is to be installed
       Depends: gcc-9 (>= 9.2.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
```

then do :

```
apt-get install cpp
```

ass you can see the depends: change from depends:gcc to depends:cpp
then do it over and over again until that same error didn't pop up and then :

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```